Mongo spring query running slow
below is my configuration
spring boot - 2.7.18
mongodb-reactivestream- 4.6.1
mongodb- 4.4.9 enterprise

below is my code
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Repository
public class MetricsRepositoryImpl implements MetricsRepository {
    private final ReactiveMongoTemplate reactiveMongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public Flux<Metric> findAllByQuery(final MetricsQuery metricsQuery) {
        
        return reactiveMongoTemplate.find(Query.query(metricsQuery.toCriteria()), Metric.class, 'metrices');

    }
}

below is my criteria
  public Criteria toCriteria() {
        return new Criteria().andOperator(
                matchIfPresent("date", date),
                matchIfPresent("source", source),
                matchIfPresent("name", portfolioName),
                matchIfPresent("shift", shift),
                anyExistIfPresent("metrics", metrics),
                byAggregationLevel(aggregationLevel),
                inIfPresent("code", code),
                matchIfPresent("id", id)
        );
    }

I see already compound index present in Mongo for the all fields present in criteria and index size is 200 GB, even after indexing my query took around 3-5 minutes to run, what else can I try to improve the performance?
Update 1:
I see it is generating below query:
{
    "$and": [{
        "date": 20241023
    },
    {
        "dataSource": "EndOfDay"
    },
    {
        "name": "my_custom_name"
    },
    {
        "aggregationLevel": "city"
    },
    {
        "shift": 0.0
    },
    {
        "$or": [{
            "metrics.metric1": {
                "$exists": true
            }
        },
        {
            "metrics.metric2": {
                "$exists": true
            }
        },
        {
            "metrics.metric3": {
                "$exists": true
            }
        },
        {
            "metrics.metric4": {
                "$exists": true
            }
        },
        {
            "metrics.metric5": {
                "$exists": true
            }
        },
        {
            "metrics.metric6": {
                "$exists": true
            }
        },
        {
            "metrics.metric7": {
                "$exists": true
            }
        }]
    },
]
}

now, if I run this query in Mongo db directly it took 65 ms whereas from my Spring Mongo took 70s (1 minute 10 seconds), I understand there's overhead when I try from application. my question is what I can do to optimize?

What index? The order of the fields in the index definition matters a lot. Can you share the .explain("allPlansExecution") output for the query?
